# Change host for Zabbix agent interface on IP change

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-api

**Requirement** : Need to update the host interface details from zabbix agent

**Actions taken** : I completed the auto registration part using Active host now i can able to communicate the server via agent using active host and HostnameItem config

```
HostnameItem=system.run[echo "Scoring_Server-ALB-`hostname -i`"]
```

- My case the internal IP doesn't change only the public ip is dynamic
- So we plan to created a host based on internal IP using above **HostnameItem**
- But We can't able to update the current public IP to zabbix host using the **zabbix agent** and **HostnameItem**
- So we trying to add the host using static Ip for this case agent create new host each IP change

```
HostnameItem=system.run[echo "Scoring_Server-ALB-`dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`"]
```

- I need to update the host interface details when the agent got new public IP
- Now the agent goes offline when the agent public ip is changed

Comment: You can use the FQDN in the Host interface. Isn't that enough?

Answer (score 0):

I have completed this requirement using  HostIntrface settings in agent

Previously i tired this setting in older version now i upgraded to current version 6.4.1 now i can able to add the function and its works fine

HostInterface function only works in zabbix agent version 6.4.1

Thanks for the responses